Dependency of t half on route of administration
If a drug is following zero order kinetics, will the t half of the drug change on basis of whether it is taken by oral route or by iv route ?

Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For reasons mentioned in this post and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. See this list of helpful resources. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?
